# C++ самый простой способ прочитать бинарный файл в unsigned char массив

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы

Какой самый простой способ чтения бинарного файла вместе со всеми его байтами (нулевыми тоже) в `unsigned char` массив и при этом узнать его длину?

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы каждый считанный байт при этом находился в отдельном элементе массива, приведенный к `int`? Почему не в массив `unsigned char`? И еще - вы имеете в виду `ifstream` или `FILE*`? И - самый простой или самый быстрый? :)

Comment: @Harry, просто я ещё новичок, больше привык работать с integer типом. Думаю `unsigned char` правда удобней.

Comment: @Harry, самый простой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, например... (проверка всяческих ошибок опущена)

```
// Файл для чтения
ifstream in("data",ios::binary);
// Создаем вектор с соответствующим размером (запрашиваем его через
// выставление указателя на конец файла)
vector<unsigned char> v(in.seekg(0,ios::end).tellg());
// Возвращаем указатель на место
in.seekg(0,ios::beg);
// Читаем файл в вектор
in.read((char*)v.data(),v.size());
```

Если добавите тэг `c`, можно будет поговорить о том, как это делать с `FILE*` :)

Comment: Не знаю, конечно, но разве не было бы проще не узнавая размер файла считывать из него, добавляя в массив?

Comment: @diraria Можно. Но проще ли? и уж точно не так быстро, как считывание всего файла одним блоком и *выделение всей памяти* один раз. Для больших файлов это может оказаться существенным.

Comment: Согласен, про скорость не подумал

Comment: А какие include нужны? Я пишу через простой текстовый редактор.

Comment: `fstream` и `vector` вроде как достаточно.